# Attempting to create a package - error PLS-00330

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am attempting to create a package with functions and procedures unfortunately I have encountered issue and the following error has occurred

> PLS-00330: invalid use of type name or subtype nameCompilation failed,line 11 (19:53:17)
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored

I have read it and done research to try fix the issue but have have not been able to fix it.

Package spec:

```
 create or replace package e_con_pack
        AS
        FUNCTION GET_LOCATION_namel (p_con_id in NUMBER, p_con_name out VARCHAR2)RETURN NUMBER;
        PROCEDURE ADD_CONSULTANT ( p_con_id           LDS_CONSULTANT.CONSULTANT_ID%type,
          p_con_name         LDS_CONSULTANT.CST_NAME%type,
          p_con_start        LDS_CONSULTANT.START_DATE%type,
          p_con_end          LDS_CONSULTANT.LEAVE_DATE%type,
          p_con_loc          LDS_CONSULTANT.LOCATION%type,
          p_con_spec         LDS_CONSULTANT.SPECIALIST_AREA%type);
          PROCEDURE update_location(p_con_id IN 
          lds_consultant.consultant_id%type,
          p_con_loc   IN lds_consultant.location%type);
          PROCEDURE delete_con (p_con_id  IN 
          lds_consultant.consultant_id%type);
          end e_con_pack;
```

Package body:

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY e_con_pack
    AS
    FUNCTION 
    GET_LOCATION_namel (p_con_id in NUMBER, p_con_name out VARCHAR2)
    RETURN NUMBER IS  
     LOCATION VARCHAR2(30);
    BEGIN
      SELECT LOCATION INTO LOCATION FROM LDS_CONSULTANT WHERE CONSULTANT_ID = p_con_id;    
      SELECT CST_NAME INTO p_con_name FROM LDS_CONSULTANT WHERE CONSULTANT_ID = p_con_id;

    RETURN NUMBER;
    END GET_LOCATION_namel;

    PROCEDURE ADD_CONSULTANT
    ( p_con_id           LDS_CONSULTANT.CONSULTANT_ID%type,
      p_con_name         LDS_CONSULTANT.CST_NAME%type,
      p_con_start        LDS_CONSULTANT.START_DATE%type,
      p_con_end          LDS_CONSULTANT.LEAVE_DATE%type,
      p_con_loc          LDS_CONSULTANT.LOCATION%type,
      p_con_spec         LDS_CONSULTANT.SPECIALIST_AREA%type)
    IS
    BEGIN

    INSERT INTO LDS_CONSULTANT (CONSULTANT_ID, CST_NAME, START_DATE, LEAVE_DATE, LOCATION, SPECIALIST_AREA)
    VALUES (p_con_id, p_con_name, p_con_start, p_con_end, p_con_loc, p_con_spec);
    END ADD_CONSULTANT;

    PROCEDURE update_location (
      p_con_id     IN lds_consultant.consultant_id%type,
      p_con_loc   IN lds_consultant.location%type
    )
    IS
    BEGIN
      UPDATE lds_consultant
        SET
          location = p_con_loc
      WHERE consultant_id = p_con_id;
    END update_location;

    PROCEDURE delete_con (
      p_con_id  IN lds_consultant.consultant_id%type )
        As
        Begin   

             Delete from LDS_CONSULTANT Where CONSULTANT_ID=p_con_id;

    END delete_con;
    END e_con_pack;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is reported against line 11 of the package body, which is

```
    RETURN NUMBER;
```

Number is a data type, not a variable name. It isn't clear what you actually want to return here; as you are querying and capturing it, perhaps `LOCATION`; but as that is a string, the return type of the function would also need to be a string (i.e. `VARCHAR2` rather than `NUMBER`). Perhaps:

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY e_con_pack
    AS
    FUNCTION 
    GET_LOCATION_namel (p_con_id in NUMBER, p_con_name out VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2 IS  
     LOCATION VARCHAR2(30);
    BEGIN
      SELECT LOCATION INTO LOCATION FROM LDS_CONSULTANT WHERE CONSULTANT_ID = p_con_id;    
      SELECT CST_NAME INTO p_con_name FROM LDS_CONSULTANT WHERE CONSULTANT_ID = p_con_id;

    RETURN LOCATION;
    END GET_LOCATION_namel;
```

Or even better, use the column data type as you already are elsewhere:

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY e_con_pack
    AS
    FUNCTION 
    GET_LOCATION_namel (p_con_id in NUMBER, p_con_name out VARCHAR2)
    RETURN LDS_CONSULTANT.LOCATION%type IS  
     LOCATION LDS_CONSULTANT.LOCATION%type;
    BEGIN
...
```

Either way, you will need to change the package specification to match, of course.

Comment: safe pal you helped me out