# Procedure with sequence error - PLS-00103 occurring need guidance

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hi stack overflow i am new to sql and im trying to create a procedure to add in new consultant. i will be re using the code in a apex application with a button to Execute the task. Also I have implemented sequence to add to new entry of consultant. Unfortunately I have the error

Compilation failed,line 10 (11:48:18)
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following: ; is with authid as cluster order using external deterministic parallel_enable pipelined result_cache accessible

could i get some guidance to address this issue as im new to sql thanks guys and research is not helping.

original code

```
create or replace procedure hirecst
       (CST_NAME VARCHAR2,
        START_DATE DATE,
        LEAVE_DATE DATE,
        LOCATION VARCHAR2,
        SPECIALIST_AREA VARCHAR2)

    RETURN NUMBER IS
       new_cst NUMBER;
    BEGIN
       SELECT CONSULTANT_IDSEQ.NEXTVAL
          INTO new_cst
          FROM DUAL;
       INSERT INTO LDS_CONSULTANT (CONSULTANT_ID, CST_NAME, START_DATE, LEAVE_DATE, LOCATION, SPECIALIST_AREA)
          VALUES (new_cst, p_con_name, p_con_start, p_con_end, p_con_loc, p_con_spec);

       RETURN(new_cst);
    END;
```

removed the return

```
create or replace procedure hirecst
   (CST_NAME VARCHAR2,
    START_DATE DATE,
    LEAVE_DATE DATE,
    LOCATION VARCHAR2,
    SPECIALIST_AREA VARCHAR2)



BEGIN
new_cst NUMBER;
   SELECT CONSULTANT_IDSEQ.NEXTVAL
      INTO new_cst
      FROM DUAL;
   INSERT INTO LDS_CONSULTANT (CONSULTANT_ID, CST_NAME, START_DATE, LEAVE_DATE, LOCATION, SPECIALIST_AREA)
      VALUES (new_cst, p_con_name, p_con_start, p_con_end, p_con_loc, p_con_spec);


END;
```

Comment: A *procedure* doesn't return anything. Are you supposed to be creating [a function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-subprograms.html#GUID-5E23F601-5194-4F40-823B-C1BD12B9248C)? (Also; [same course](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50319592/266304)? *8-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use "return" in stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225532/is-it-possible-to-use-return-in-stored-procedure)

Comment: nope ive removed the return and it returned a different error

Comment: That was the immediate problem with the error you posted. You've edited the question to not have that problem now; but you also removed the `IS` from that line. (There are other issues; where are `p_con_name` etc. coming from? Are those supposed to be the names of the procedure arguments? And you don't need the `new_cst` variable - you can use the sequence directly in the insert statement.)

Comment: You don't need `select CONSULTANT_IDSEQ.NEXTVAL into new_cst from dual;`. Simply make `new_cst := CONSULTANT_IDSEQ.NEXTVAL;` resp. `INSERT INTO LDS_CONSULTANT (...) VALUES (CONSULTANT_IDSEQ.NEXTVAL, ...);` if you need the value only once.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I am ignoring the apparent mismatch between the declared parameter names and the ones used in the INSERT statement.

---

[As documented in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_procedure.htm#LNPLS01373) you need the `AS` (or `IS`) keyword that starts the actual procedure part - after which the variable declaration needs to be written:

```
create or replace procedure hirecst
   (CST_NAME VARCHAR2,
    START_DATE DATE,
    LEAVE_DATE DATE,
    LOCATION VARCHAR2,
    SPECIALIST_AREA VARCHAR2)
AS --<< HERE
  new_cst NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT CONSULTANT_IDSEQ.NEXTVAL
      INTO new_cst
      FROM DUAL;

   INSERT INTO LDS_CONSULTANT 
      (CONSULTANT_ID, CST_NAME, START_DATE, LEAVE_DATE, LOCATION, SPECIALIST_AREA)
    VALUES 
      (new_cst, p_con_name, p_con_start, p_con_end, p_con_loc, p_con_spec);
END;
```

---

However, the SELECT INTO is not required at all, you can use `nextval` directly in the `INSERT` statement. So you can simplify the procedure to:

```
create or replace procedure hirecst
   (CST_NAME VARCHAR2,
    START_DATE DATE,
    LEAVE_DATE DATE,
    LOCATION VARCHAR2,
    SPECIALIST_AREA VARCHAR2)
AS --<< Still needed!
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO LDS_CONSULTANT 
     (CONSULTANT_ID, CST_NAME, START_DATE, LEAVE_DATE, LOCATION, SPECIALIST_AREA)
   VALUES 
     (CONSULTANT_IDSEQ.NEXTVAL, p_con_name, p_con_start, p_con_end, p_con_loc, p_con_spec);
END;
```

---

If you want to return the generated ID from the procedure you need an `OUT` parameter:

```
create or replace procedure hirecst
   (CST_NAME VARCHAR2,
    START_DATE DATE,
    LEAVE_DATE DATE,
    LOCATION VARCHAR2,
    SPECIALIST_AREA VARCHAR2, 
    p_consultant_id out integer) --<< HERE
AS 
BEGIN
   -- Assign the value to the OUT parameter
   p_consultant_id := CONSULTANT_IDSEQ.NEXTVAL;

   INSERT INTO LDS_CONSULTANT 
      (CONSULTANT_ID, CST_NAME, START_DATE, LEAVE_DATE, LOCATION, SPECIALIST_AREA)
    VALUES 
      (p_consultant_id, p_con_name, p_con_start, p_con_end, p_con_loc, p_con_spec);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the syntax of procedre-

```
CREATE [OR REPLACE] PROCEDURE procedure_name
    [ (parameter [,parameter]) ]

IS
    [declaration_section]

BEGIN
    executable_section

[EXCEPTION
    exception_section]

END [procedure_name];
```

And you forget 'IS' keyword

```
following is the code-

    create or replace procedure hirecst
           (CST_NAME VARCHAR2,
            START_DATE DATE,
            LEAVE_DATE DATE,
            LOCATION VARCHAR2,
            SPECIALIST_AREA VARCHAR2)

         IS
           new_cst NUMBER;
        begin
           SELECT CONSULTANT_IDSEQ.NEXTVAL
              INTO new_cst
              FROM DUAL;
           INSERT INTO LDS_CONSULTANT (CONSULTANT_ID, CST_NAME, START_DATE, LEAVE_DATE, LOCATION, SPECIALIST_AREA)
              VALUES (new_cst, p_con_name, p_con_start, p_con_end, p_con_loc, p_con_spec);

           end;
        ;
```